# Is it possible to define the Point Spread Function for a lens?

Tags: lenses

I have seen several papers and reports in which the Point Spread Function (PSF) of a microscope is calculated and measured. In particular, as far as I understand, a light point source is placed in the specimen's plane along the focal axis of the objective (i.e. in the objective's focal point), and the light intensity distribution obtained after the microscope is the PSF.

Is it possible to introduce the concept of PSF also for an optical system composed by just one single lens (maybe a simple converging lens, for the sake of finding a simple case)?
In such a case, where should I place the point source to get the PSF?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Best Regards!